# Nvarchar value overflowing an int column where there is no int column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How is my nvarchar value overflowing an int column when I'm not defining any int values?

I'm getting the following error when I run my stored procedure:

```
The conversion of the nvarchar value '17191925814' overflowed an int column.
```

The statement I was trying to execute:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[updateUser] @status = 'active', ..... ,@srcID = '17191925814'
```

The problem is that I never define that value as an int. It is always handled as a string, as far as I can tell. In my stored procedure the @srcID parameter is defined as an nvarchar(255):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateUser] ... , @srcID nvarchar(255), ...
```

And within that stored procedure, I try to UPDATE a value in a column that is also defined as nvarchar(255):

```
IF @srcID NOT IN ('', '0') AND @srcID IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [Source System ID] = @srcID WHERE ...
ELSE IF @srcID = '0'
    UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [Source System ID] = '' WHERE ...
```

The target table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] ( ..., [Source System ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL, ...)
```

Where, or why, is SQL Server trying to convert '17191925814' to an int, and how can I prevent it?

Edit: I've included the full code of the stored procedure where the parameter @srcID appears.

Comment: Somewhere along the way, that value is being treated as an int.  This often happens when comparing to an integer or when using `+`.

Comment: `17191925814` is exceeding the maximum value for `INT`, its maximum is `-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)`, use `BIGINT` instead.

Comment: If you could post the enitre code of the stored procedure, it would probably help us find the problem (I agree with Gordon - probably an implicit conversion somewhere in the code)

Comment: I'll post it in the question

Comment: we need more code, it's nowhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Use `SSMS` for Debugging to fetch where exactly the error raises,

Comment: If you're *absolutely*, 100% certain that it's not there (a complete procedure from `CREATE PROCEDURE` down to the end would be more reassuring than the fragments), look to see if there are any triggers on the table.

Comment: The full code is 270 lines, and I've included all occurrences of that variable. It just repeats the same code as shown above with different columns/parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you so much! There was indeed a trigger to copy all updates into an archive table, and that archive still had int as the data type for the [Source System ID] column. I would have never found that by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out by Damian in the comments, was that I had a trigger active on the database, that was copying that data into an integer column.

So if you have this same issue: check triggers on your database!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't want to be specific answer (I agree with Gordon, Zohar and Damien), but should be difficult to write in a comment.
Follow a "reduced" procedure to show the case.
I hope it can help you as a method when you have similar problems (always try to reduce the scope), and serve as a confirmation of what Gordon, Zohar and other (I know, there is no need of confirmation as they have great reputation :-) already said:

```
CREATE TABLE X ( SourceSystemID nvarchar(255) NULL);
INSERT INTO X VALUES ('17191925814');
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Upd_X @srcID NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
IF @srcID NOT IN ('', '0') AND @srcID IS NOT NULL    UPDATE X SET SourceSystemID = @srcID  
ELSE IF @srcID = '0' UPDATE X SET SourceSystemID = '' 
END
;
GO
SELECT * FROM X
EXEC Upd_X '17191925814';
SELECT * FROM X;
```

Output:

```
SourceSystemID
---------------
17191925814


SourceSystemID
-----------------------------------------
17191925814
```

Comment: Thank you pointing this out, and helping me structure my SQL problem solving process.